# Optimal LED circuit design

Tags: voltage, led, current, optimization

I have a personal project.  I must create a circuit with 20 LED (20 mA, 2.0 V) on a battery car supply (12 V). So my question is, which mode is optimal? I designed two schematics:

1. 4x LEDs in series with resistor (multiply by 5) -> 5 x 20 mA -> 0.1 A
2. 5x LEDs in series with resistor (multiply by 4) -> 4 x 20 mA -> 0.08 A

I want uniform brightness, no heating in time, and a long life for my circuit.

Which case is optimal? If you have another case, please tell me (maybe 2x LEDs or something, I don’t know). I’m newbie in this domain, so I do not know so much about optimization.

[image: Case 1- not real values]

[image: Case 2- not real values]

Comment: What do you mean by "optimal"?

Comment: Best case, most efficient circuit. I didn't know exactly, but I think if exist more than two cases, one of them is better

Comment: Most efficient circuit with only resistors may not be best. If the car battery voltage varies then the less efficient circuit may be better. Do you want more even brightness even with varying battery voltage, or can you accept large brightness changes? Most efficient circuit would not even use resistors but a buck or boost power supply. Such a power supply is also more expensive than just resistors. So we don't know what you mean by best if you do not define it.

Comment: Do you have to use 20 separate smaller LEDs, or will one larger LED which is more efficient suffice? What is the application for this?

Comment: @SkePsis *Optimal* isn't a single thing, like "highest." It's a balancing act that takes into account all of the necessary goals. And even then, it's still a matter of opinion with N engineers providing from 5*N to (N+1)! viewpoints, whichever is larger. You have written: (1) *uniform brightness*; and, (2) *no heating in time*; and, (3) *a long life for my circuit*. There's more, of course. The battery voltage isn't the same during use. It changes. This means that with only passive devices you will be sacrificing *uniform brightness* as the battery is used. And that's just for starters.

Answer (score 3):

If you work out the power dissipated in the resistors, which is wasted power, you will be able to figure out which arrangement is most efficient.

Do remember that if the battery is in a car electrical system then the system will be running at about 14.4 V, instead of 12 V, when the engine is running.

You can get around the varying voltage of a car electrical system by using a current regulator: LEDs give a consistent output with a constant current. There are low-cost 20 mA constant-current LED driver ICs available which are suitable for automotive use, such as the [CL2](https://www.microchip.com/en-us/product/CL2) (that's just what I found: I have no practical experience doing this).

What I do have experience of is getting similar brightness from a bag of cheap LEDs: make some set-up, perhaps a small breadboard supplied with a low voltage and with resistors that give 20 mA so that you can compare the brightness of a batch of maybe 8 or 10 LEDs at the same time, and reject the ones that look too bright or too dim. You want the LEDs in parallel because bags of cheap LEDs may include 1% of dead ones, and you don't need the fun of finding the dead Christmas tree light as that should not happen more than once a year.

(If you go with a current regulator, you might want to get more than you need so that you can match the current output from them, as the manufacturing tolerance could be 10% on the current.)

Comment: Thank you, for sure i will get more infos about CL2. Thank you for advices again

Comment: @SkePsis Beyond the basic "I want a few strings of LEDs" problem, you are likely to get better answers than mine by editing your question to add the exact use of the LEDs, if you can. For example, you might want car underglow where one strip failing is tragic, or perhaps a small panel of LEDs in a boat next to a cooker where one strip failing is not such a problem. Should the LEDs be able to drain the battery to the point that the battery is destroyed, or is it OK for them to go out when the battery is quite low?

Comment: The LEDs will be mounted on a custom round PCB to obtain a second turn signal on VW Golf 5. I will design PCB with voltage regulator ( now, max voltage is 12.4V) so I think voltage isn't a big problem. For this case, matching brightness with the original turn system can be a problem.